# Branch.io API implementation in C#

Tags: c#, api, branch.io

I want to implement Branch.io API in my app. Server-side is .Net and I could not find any solution for API implementation in C#. Every document in Branch.io for working with API refers to giving the response by Postman and nothing with C#!

Is there any way or it just implement in Client-side?

Comment: try to be more explanatory. what did you to make it happen and what went wrong?

Comment: @OzanTopal thank you, really I want to know how to use branch.io API in C#, in my page I have a list of items can be shared and I should use branch.io API for generating these links. I read this document: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api but I don't understand the request items and it is not clear. I need to send link create response as a sharing URL for every item of that list I mentioned to the Client.

Comment: did you use HttpClient class from .net framework before? you can make http requests with help of this client.

Comment: @OzanTopal my comment was updated, about your question I never used it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not best looking code but works for your task:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string branch_key { get; set; }
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string feature { get; set; }
    public string campaign { get; set; }
    public string stage { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string canonical_identifier { get; set; }
    public string og_title { get; set; }
    public string og_description { get; set; }
    public string og_image_url { get; set; }
    public string desktop_url { get; set; }
    public bool custom_boolean { get; set; }
    public int custom_integer { get; set; }
    public string custom_string { get; set; }
    public int[] custom_array { get; set; }
    public Custom_Object custom_object { get; set; }
}

public class Custom_Object
{
    public string random { get; set; }
}
```

These classes which are above is data to send. And request method should be like:

```
public async Task GetUrlData(string url, string branchKey)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.branch.io");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string requestUrl = $"/v1/url?url{url}&key={branchKey}";

            var payload = new Rootobject();

            var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, httpContent);

            if (response.Content != null)
            {
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
```

responseContent variable is the response of api what you're looking for.``